# C++ function pointer works but std::function not

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates

I'm going to make a benchmark function, which measures the elapsed time of given function execution and returns execution result and elapsed time.

```cpp
template <typename TResult>
struct BenchmarkResult{
    TResult result;
    const long elapsed;
};

template <typename Ratio, typename TResult, typename... TParams>
BenchmarkResult<TResult> benchmark(TResult (*function)(TParams...), TParams ...params){
    using namespace std::chrono;

    const auto begin = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto result = function(std::forward<TParams>(params)...);
    const auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

    return { std::move(result), duration_cast<Ratio>(end - begin).count() };
}
```

And for example,

```cpp
int sleep(int seconds){
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    return seconds * 1e6; // return the given second in microsecond unit
}

// (implement above code)

int main(){ 
    auto [elapsed_us, elapsed_ms] = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(sleep, 1);
    std::cout << "Elapsed ms: " << elapsed_ms << " Elapsed us: " << elapsed_us;;

    return 0;
}
```

Will output like

> Elapsed ms: 1005 Elapsed us: 1000000

My goal is to change the argument type like `BenchmarkResult<TResult> benchmark(std::function<TResult(TParams...)> function, TParams ...params)`. But it does not works for the above example in the latest C++ version.

The compiler says,

```
/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
/main.cpp:76:73: error: no matching function for call to 'benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(int (&)(int), int)'
   76 |     auto [elapsed_us, elapsed_ms] = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(sleep, 1);
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/main.cpp:54:26: note: candidate: 'template<class Ratio, class TResult, class ... TParams> BenchmarkResult<TResult> benchmark(std::function<TResult(TParams ...)>, TParams ...)'
   54 | BenchmarkResult<TResult> benchmark(std::function<TResult(TParams...)> function, TParams ...params){ // TODO: use std::function instead of function pointer
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~
/main.cpp:54:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/main.cpp:76:73: note:   mismatched types 'std::function<TResult(TParams ...)>' and 'int (*)(int)'
   76 |     auto [elapsed_us, elapsed_ms] = benchmark<std::chrono::milliseconds>(sleep, 1);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: My recommendation is that you look at how the standard library handles callable objects: Using a single templated argument. As in `template<typename FuncT, typename ValueT> void call(FuncT function, ValueT const& value) { function(value); }`

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Details matter. Includes matter. renaming makes it compile, not sure why though https://godbolt.org/z/o7v7P9z8T.

Comment: Then how can result type be deduced?

Comment: Function arguments that participate in template argument deduction can't undergo implicit conversions, so you're out of luck. Use Someprogrammerdude's advice. For the return type, either use `decltype` or `std::invoke_result_t` (then also use `std::invoke` to call the functor).

Comment: Don't forget to pass the extra arguments using `&&` forwarding references and `std::forward` (same for the functor, IMO).